# Auto Flush not working for Spring 3.1 LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean + Hibernate 4 + Websphere JTA

Tags: spring, hibernate, websphere, jta

I have did a lot of search on the web and pages like [this](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?126363-Session-not-flushed-with-Hibernate-4-1-3-JTA-and-Spring-transaction-management-integ) and [this](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-9480) and [this](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-9404) mostly suggested for using CMTTransactionFactory.  However I am still unable to make it work (I wonder if it is because I am creating a EM using a LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean instead of creating Hibernate session by LocalSessionFactoryBean)

My App Service looks something like:

```
@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
public class FooServiceImpl implements FooService {
  @Inject
  private FooRepository fooRepo;

  public void doSomething() {
    Foo foo = fooRepo.findBySomething(...);
    foo.setBar(...);
    //fooRepo.flush();     // un-comment to do manual-flushing
  }
}
```

Here is the snippet in my app ctx

```
<jee:jndi-lookup  id="dataSource" jndi-name="jdbc/fooDs" />

<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.WebSphereUowTransactionManager" />

<bean id="emf" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect" />
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="foo" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.foo" />
    <!--
      <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath:/META-INF/test-persistence.xml" />
     -->
    <property name="jpaPropertyMap">
        <map>
            <entry key="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect" />
              <entry key="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class" value="org.hibernate.transaction.WebSphereExtendedJTATransactionLookup" />
              <entry key="hibernate.transaction.factory_class" value="org.hibernate.transaction.CMTTransactionFactory"/>

            <entry key="hibernate.transaction.flush_before_completion"  value = "true" />
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

I am making use of Spring Data JPA and after the entity is retrieved, I updated the content.  If I am not flushing the repository manually (which means session/entityManager) manually, it simply discard my changes.

Can anyone give me some hints on what I have missed in the setting?  Is there anything special to notice for using LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean?

I tried to change the jpaProperty entry of manager_lookup_class to 
`hibernate.transaction.jta.platform  => org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.WebSphereExtendedJtaPlatform` but it does not help.

I also tried to use `org.hibernate.transaction.JTATransactionFactory` as `transaction factory class`, or even remove the `transaction factory class`.  Such change seems makes Hibernate unable to pickup the transaction.  When I am manually flushing the repository, it simply give me a `javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException` with message `no transaction is in progress`

I am using Spring 3.1.2.RELEASE, JPA with Hibernate 4.1.6.Final, Websphere 8

Is there anyone using the above combination and have a working config that I can follow?

---

Edit: I have tried to inject EntityManager to the service to avoid using Spring Data JPA.  The symptom is the same: I have to explicitly call entityManager.flush() to let Hibernate pickup the updated entities.  At least we can take Spring Data out of picture :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have raised discussion in other forum.  Here is the link that contains the reason behind.

http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?131051-Auto-Flush-not-working-for-Spring-3-1-LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean-Hibernate-4-JTA

It is caused by, the above combination is going to setup the entity manager with transaction type being RESOURCE_LOCAL.  This is not working with the above combination of libraries' version (while it works when using Spring 2.5 + Hibernate 3).

A workaround for the problem is to declare the transaction type being JTA (by providing a `persistence.xml`).

A better solution is provided in later version of Spring, which LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean provides a jtaDataSource property (https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-9883)

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is this entry.

```
<entry key="hibernate.transaction.factory_class" value="org.hibernate.transaction.CMTTransactionFactory"/>
```

Remove that and the auto flush works after the transaction has completed.  Seems like with that entry added you have to manually call entity manager flush.